# What data has JWST obtained of the Trappist-1 exoplanets and where is it?

Tags: exoplanet, spectroscopy, james-webb-space-telescope, trappist-1

I have been long waiting spectral data regarding the exoplanets around Trappist-1 and their atmospheres, and I was also long awaiting JWST's launch to get to know more about the system. However, now that multiple months have passed and scheduled observations of Trappist-1 have been made, where is the data? So far best I have seen was some Redditor posting an image he claims he made with the raw data a while ago, but other than that I have seen nothing, not from NASA, not on google, not on scientific articles, I am not claiming there is any sort of conspiracy or anything like that, I just want to know if I am missing something here?

Comment: The data may be available on the MAST archive for you to see yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first things that come up for me when I google "get JWST data"
are lots of websites and even Youtube videos telling me exactly how to download data from the [MAST archive](https://mast.stsci.edu/portal/Mashup/Clients/Mast/Portal.html)

There are indeed lots of JWST data on Trappist-1 in the MAST archive - 165 data files in total. Just go to this site, search by "Trappist-1" and then click the filter for JWST data.

You will see in the list that there are imaging data from the MIRI and NIRISS through various filters and NIRSPEC spectroscopy.

Some of the data are freely available but some are embargoed for 12 months because various research groups will have made proposals to obtain the data and are granted a certain amount of time to exclusively do their research on that data before it is released more widely. The JWST policy on that can be read [here](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-opportunities-and-policies/past-jwst-proposal-opportunities/jwst-cycle-1-guaranteed-time-observations-call-for-proposals/jwst-cycle-1-gto-proposal-submission-policies). Some of the data are also in the planning stage - i.e. they are placeholders for observations that haven't been done yet.

Here is a raw NIRSPEC spectrum of Trappist-1. I don't know what you make of it, but then I haven't read any of the extensive JWST data processing/reduction documentation and haven't carefully studied exactly what has been observed, with the slit in what position. Note that fully extracted and processed data are not currently available.

[image: NIRSPEC spectrum of Trappist-1]

Note that JWST observed the star Trappist-1. As explained in [Has NASA released any JWST images of Trappist-1? If not, why?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50502/has-nasa-released-any-jwst-images-of-trappist-1-if-not-why) , the angular resolution and contrast abilities of JWST are not sufficient to obtain separately resolved images or spectra of its exoplanets. Any spectrum of an exoplanet would be inferred by comparing the observed spectrum of the star and the star+exoplanet in and out of eclipse.